# Manipulate object data to get specific result

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Ok I'm having a brain fart. I need to pull out the value for "data" as described below...

```
(UPDATED:) console.log(d.body) gives me...
 {
    "data": [{
        "id": "30220059",
        "login": "esl_sc2",
        "display_name": "ESL_SC2",
        "type": "",
        "broadcaster_type": "partner",
        "description": "For standings, schedule, and results, visit https://pro.eslgaming.com/tour/sc2/",
        "profile_image_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/cac110f7-0711-421f-9341-c77b53ab63b5-profile_image-300x300.jpeg",
        "offline_image_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ac0e240d-63c2-4faf-9040-60543b3e2c0f-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.jpeg",
        "view_count": 0,
        "created_at": "2012-05-02T09:59:20Z"
    }]
}
```

What do I need to do on `d.body` to get the output to look like this?

```
{
    "id": "30220059",
    "login": "esl_sc2",
    "display_name": "ESL_SC2",
    "type": "",
    "broadcaster_type": "partner",
    "description": "For standings, schedule, and results, visit https://pro.eslgaming.com/tour/sc2/",
    "profile_image_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/cac110f7-0711-421f-9341-c77b53ab63b5-profile_image-300x300.jpeg",
    "offline_image_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ac0e240d-63c2-4faf-9040-60543b3e2c0f-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.jpeg",
    "view_count": 0,
    "created_at": "2012-05-02T09:59:20Z"
}
```

I thought it was simply `d.body.data[0]`?

Comment: It _is_ simply just `d.body.data[0]`. If that doesn't work then your `d` object isn't actually what you think it is at the time you're trying to access the data within it (also `const d.body = { ... }` will be a syntax error, so I'm guessing there's more to what you're showing us here)

Comment: My best guess is that you're trying to access the data within the `d` object _before_ the `body` property etc. has been added to it. Even if using a console log shows that it has data in it, that can't be trusted as console's typically [log a live reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects) of the object, so it would be showing you the object as it is at the time you're viewing it in the console, not at the time it was log (where it may not have the nested data you're after).

Comment: you have invalid JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Comment: @NickParsons  I updated the question. console.log(d.body) gives me the described output. Turns out typeof d.body is my friend here. It was returning a string not an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out typeof d.body is my friend here. It was returning a string not an object.

Comment: The color of the console output also helps there.

Answer (score -2):

you can get direct the json using the following Destructuring assignment

[Destructuring assignment][1]

```js
let { body: { data: [data = {}] = [0] }} = {
    "body":{
        "data":[
            {
                "id":"30220059",
                "login":"esl_sc2",
                "display_name":"ESL_SC2",
                "type":"",
                "broadcaster_type":"partner",
                "description":"For standings, schedule, and results, visit https://pro.eslgaming.com/tour/sc2/",
                "profile_image_url":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/cac110f7-0711-421f-9341-c77b53ab63b5-profile_image-300x300.jpeg",
                "offline_image_url":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/ac0e240d-63c2-4faf-9040-60543b3e2c0f-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.jpeg",
                "view_count":0,
                "created_at":"2012-05-02T09:59:20Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}

console.log(data)
```

Comment: thefonso, why not use the Destructuring , I mean at the end you can use whatever you want, but the Destructuring was created for those cases.